# Text summarization dataset

Tags: text, dataset, summarization

Does anyone has the text summarization dataset containing the text and the summaries of the text?

I found http://www.nist.gov/tac/data/past/2009/Summ09.html, but for the distribution of it they need lot of paper work and authorization.

Can somebody help me here please?

Comment: You could check answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959104/dataset-link-for-text-summarization

Answer (score 0):

There are strict rules about distributing TAC data, you can request access to the data but will have to fill in some forms first:

TAC: http://www.nist.gov/tac/data/forms/index.html

Comment: This isn't a very good answer. It should have been a comment on their question.

Answer (score -1):

The dataset should be used only if you have an agreement with NIST for the data. Try signing an agreement and get some authorization from your organization.

Comment: This isn't a very good answer. It should have been a comment on their question.